# How to get Sum(Column) over (partition by other columns)?

Tags: hive

I am trying to convert Teradata code written like below

```
Select A.col1, sum(A.metric1) over (partition by A.col1, B.col1 order by   
  A.col2 asc) as Cust_col, B.col1 from A JOIN B on (A.join_key=B.join_key) 
  where A.col3='X' QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY A.col1,B.COL1
  ORDER BY A.col3 DESC) = 1
```

In Hive:

```
Select C.col1,C.cust_col,C.col1,ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY A.col1,C.COL1 
  ORDER BY C.col3 DESC) as Row_num from (Select A.col1, sum(A.metric1) over 
  (partition by A.col1, B.col1 order by A.col2 asc) as Cust_col,B.col1 from A 
  JOIN B on (A.join_key=B.join_key) where A.col3='X') C where C.Row_num =1
```

But, I am getting error like

> SemanticException Failed to breakup Windowing invocations into Groups.
>   At least 1 group must only depend on input columns. Also check for
>   circular dependencies. Underlying error: Primitve type DATE not
>   supported in Value Boundary expression

I know it is because with `Sum(A.metric1)` partition is creating a problem here, but how to resolve this?

Comment: I don't know Hive but I think it there is also something like a schema. And I think it would help to see at least the types of the columns.

Comment: I did not understand.. sorry.

Comment: Wrong reference: where C.ROW_NUM=1. C.row_num does not exists. Use sub-query to filter by row_num

Comment: Hello leftjoin, indeed I am doing row_num operation inside the query and filtering the duplicates using C.Row_num=1... I am not sure am I clear with my requirement.

Comment: Which column is DATE? it is not clear. is it col3 which is used in order by?

Comment: Yes, Col3 used in order by is a date column... If I remove that, query works fine... will validate data, I did similar to what you outlined below but included sum(metric) over partition column in subquery itself...not sure how removing order by makes any difference in data...

Comment: Sorry for late reply, this has been resolved by removing the order by field from the sum(metric1) over (partition .....) column, not sure how it is working and I am getting syntax right and the correct data after removing... but would like to know how it is working... any thoughts??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select a_col1,
       sum(metric1) over (partition by a_col1, b_col1 order by a_col2 asc) as Cust_col, 
       b_col1
from
(
Select A.metric1, A.col1 a_col1, B.COL1 b_col1, A.col2 a_col2
       ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY A.col1,B.COL1 ORDER BY A.col3 DESC ) as rn
from A JOIN B on (A.join_key=B.join_key) 
  where A.col3='X' 

) s 
where rn=1
```